# Нужна помощь с sharedpraference

Tags: java, android

Суть такая, имеется главная activity, потом 4 фрагмента, один из них что-то вроде настроек заполненный radiogrupp и 3-мя radiobutton соответствующих каждому из 3-х оставшихся фрагментов. Как сделать так, чтобы при старте приложения выводило так: если первый radiobutton нажат выводило первый фрагмент, второй нажат второй фрагмент и т.д. При закрытии все сохранялось??? Могу привести код если надо. Мне нужен пример как это реализовать, особенно сохранение положения радикнопок после закрытия приложения.

Comment: очень много неточностей, вы используете PreferenceFragment с радиоБат? я не помню чтоб там такие были вроде чекбоксы ща все делают. А значит это обычный фрагмент, тогда используйте все ручками. Пишите в SharedPref когда нужно и считывайте данные когда нужно. всё логично

Comment: @ShwarzAndrei уже решил проблему